# Split json response item into multiple items in Python

Tags: python, sql, json

I am currently trying to parse a JSON file from an API. Currently, I can read each item in the response and parse the data into variables, which I am using to create a SQL statement for importing into a table. Here is some sample code:

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": 64731,
"label": "Label Text goes here",
"locations": [
    {
    "id": "55925",
    "label": "San Miguel (La Dorada)",
    "self": "http://url.com/api/locations/55925"
    }
 ],
"other_location": "Other location text goes here",
"subject": "Subject Text goes here",
"url": "http://www.url.com"
},
]
}
```

My python script can read each entry in the json and import each entry as row in a table with id, label, location, other_location, subject, and url as fields.

However, for some entries, I have multiple locations, so what I would like to do is basically repeat the same entry for each of the locations and only change the location information. So therefore this:

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": 64731,
"label": "Label Text goes here",
"locations": [
    {
    "id": "55925",
    "label": "San Miguel (La Dorada)",
    "self": "http://url.com/api/locations/55925"
    },
    {
    "id": "55926",
    "label": "Istanbul",
    "self": "http://url.com/api/locations/55926"
    }
 ],
"other_location": "Other location text goes here",
"subject": "Subject Text goes here",
"url": "http://www.url.com"
},
]
}
```

would actually be two rows in my table, each with the same data except the location would be different. How should I modify my working script in order to split an entry in multiple entries? (Note some of the variables are coming from nested jsons in the location field, but it should not really make a difference for what I am trying to do)

```
def insert_into_table(sql_query):
try:
    print cl.sql(sql_query)
except Exception as e:
   print ("some error ocurred", e)

def main():
  # define a variable to hold the source URL
  urlData = "http://www.url.com/api"

  # Open the URL and read the data
  webUrl = urllib2.urlopen(urlData)
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
      data = webUrl.read()

    # Use the json module to load the string data into a dictionary
      api_url = json.loads(data)

      for i in api_url["data"]:
        id = i["id"]
        label = i["label"]

        #variablea for nested locations JSON
        location_api = i["locations"][0]["self"]
        location_id = i["locations"][0]["id"]
        location_label = i["locations"][0]["label"]
        #checks connection and loads the json
        openlocations = urllib2.urlopen(location_api)
        if (openlocations.getcode() == 200):
            location_data = openlocations.read()
            load_locations = json.loads(location_data)

            #defining the variable to be inserted into table from the nested JSON
            geoid = load_locations["data"][0]["id"]
            geo_pcode = load_locations["data"][0]["pcode"]
            geo_iso_code = load_locations["data"][0]["iso3"]
            geo_admin_level = load_locations["data"][0]["admin_level"]
            lat = load_locations["data"][0]["geolocation"]["lat"]
            long = load_locations["data"][0]["geolocation"]["lon"]
            #dive into the nested locations to find admin level 0 which is the country name
            country = ""
            if geo_admin_level == "0":
                country = location_label
               #redeclares the location as null if the location is also the country
                location_label = "null"
            # finds, opens and loads the nested location url if necessary
            elif geo_admin_level == "1":
                geo_parent_url = load_locations["data"][0]["parent"][0]["self"]
                open_geoparent = urllib2.urlopen(geo_parent_url)
                if (open_geoparent.getcode() == 200):
                    geoparent_data = open_geoparent.read()
                    load_geoparent_data = json.loads(geoparent_data)
                    parent_geo_admin_level = load_geoparent_data["data"][0]["admin_level"]
                    if parent_geo_admin_level == "0":
                        country = load_geoparent_data["data"][0]["label"]
                    # finds, opens and loads the nested location url if necessary
                    elif parent_geo_admin_level == "1":
                        geo_grandparent_url = load_geoparent_data["data"][0]["parent"][0]["self"]
                        open_geograndparent = urllib2.urlopen(geo_grandparent_url)
                        if (open_geograndparent.getcode() == 200):
                            geo_grandparent_data = open_geograndparent.read()
                            load_geograndparent_data = json.loads(geo_grandparent_data)
                            grandparent_geo_admin_level = load_geograndparent_data["data"][0]["admin_level"]
                            if grandparent_geo_admin_level == "0":
                                country = load_geograndparent_data["data"][0]["label"]
                            # finds, opens and loads the nested location url if necessary
                            elif grandparent_geo_admin_level == "1":
                                geo_greatgrandparent_url = load_geograndparent_data["data"][0]["parent"][0]["self"]
                                open_geogreatgrandparent = urllib2.urlopen(geo_greatgrandparent_url)
                                if (open_geogreatgrandparent.getcode() == 200):
                                    geo_greatgrandparent_data = open_geogreatgrandparent.read()
                                    load_geogreatgrandparent_data = json.loads(geo_greatgrandparent_data)
                                    greatgrandparent_geo_admin_level = load_geogreatgrandparent_data["data"][0]["admin_level"]
                                    if greatgrandparent_geo_admin_level == "0":
                                        country = load_geogreatgrandparent_data["data"][0]["label"]
                                    else:
                                        #leaving as null for testing purposes if dive into 5th level
                                        country = "null"
                                else:
                                    print "GreatGrandparent location url does not exist or cannot be opened. Code: " + str(open_geogreatgrandparent.getcode())
                        else:
                             print "Grandparent location url does not exist or cannot be opened. Code: " + str(open_geograndparent.getcode())

                else:
                    print "Parent location url does not exist or cannot be opened. Code: " + str(open_geoparent.getcode())

            else:
                print "Primary Admin Level was not level 0 or 1"        
        #prints error mesage if connection fails   
        else:
            print "Cannot open locations url. Code: " + str(openlocations.getcode())

        other_location = i["other_location"]
        subject = i["subject"]
        assessment_url = i["url"]

        try:
            sql_query = "INSERT INTO table_name (lat_lon, id, label, location_id, location_label, country, geoid, geo_pcode, geo_iso_code, geo_admin_level, other_location, subject, assessment_url) VALUES ("
            sql_query = sql_query + "'SRID=4326; POINT (%f %f)', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'" % (float(str(long)), float(str(lat)), id, label, id, label, location_id, location_label, country, geoid, geo_pcode, geo_iso_code, geo_admin_level, other_location, subject, assessment_url)
             sql_query = sql_query + ")"
             print str(sql_query)
         except ValueError,e:
            print ("some error ocurred", e)

        #This is where you call insert_into_table()
        insert_into_table(sql_query)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the `i["locations"]` list.

Change this:

```
#variables for nested locations JSON
location_api = i["locations"][0]["self"]
location_id = i["locations"][0]["id"]
location_label = i["locations"][0]["label"]
```

To the following:

```
#variables for nested locations JSON
for loc in i["locations"]:
    location_api = loc["self"]
    location_id = loc["id"]
    location_label = loc["label"]
    <...rest of your code...>
```

[Python Standard Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I can do that easily, but how would I modify my SQL query statement in order to insert each iteration as a new row?

Comment: The rest of your code (including the SQL query generation and querying the DB) should be within the `for` loop that I wrote. The code will get executed multiple times and hence multiple rows will be inserted.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It is only partially working though. For some reason when I print into the console they show up a separate entries, but when I check the table, only one row with the first location is actually being inserted. Any advice?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I had to move my insert function into the for loop as well and it was fine. Thanks again!